# Outlook getting a default email

Tags: c#, outlook, netoffice

I need to get the default email (which is selected in File > Account Settings > Account Settings).

I have tried to get it in different ways:

```
var outlookApp = new Application();
var defaultEmail = OutlookApp.Session.DefaultStore.DisplayName;

var outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
defaultEmail = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Store.DisplayName;

defaultEmail = outlookNamespace.DefaultStore.DisplayName;
```

But all ways return the email of my Exchange account, not the default email I chose (e.g. myExample@gmail.com).
Is there any way to get the default email?

Comment: Got the default email this way:
``OutlookApp.Session.Accounts.FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName``.

But I'm not sure if this is the optimal way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry`.

From there, you can either use `AddressEntry.Address` or, in case of an Exchange account, `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`

Comment: Unfortunately, both suggested ways only return the email of my Exchange mail, not the one I added via smtp/imap and assigned by default. Only ``outlookApp.Session.Accounts.FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName`` works correctly. But I don't like this way. It doesn't work if you reassign the default email and don't restart Outlook

Comment: If you prefer to work with the accounts, use `Account.SmtpAddress` property rather than `Account.DisplayName`